# Converter string UTF-8 para formato padrão do C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou fazendo download de uma string via `WebClient()` e recebo uma string com os acentos mal formados.

**Exemplo:**

> `{"fÃ­ddiesticks":{"id":4078584,"name":"FÃ­ddIesticks","profileIconId":946,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1475092874000}}`

Eu sei que a `string` que eu recebo está em `UTF-8`, mas não estou conseguindo converter para o formato padrão do `C#` que eu na verdade nem sei qual é.

Código:

```
private void buttonSummonerBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClientSummonerInfo0 = new WebClient();
    webClientSummonerInfo0.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(SummonerInfo0_DownloadStringCompleted);
    webClientSummonerInfo0.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://br.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + comboBoxSummonerRegion.SelectedItem + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + textBoxSummonerName.Text + "?api_key=" + __apiKey));

}

private void SummonerInfo0_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
}
```

Comment: você configurou para receber em UTF-8? Como está seu código!

Comment: No site, a informação está em UTF-8, assim que eu recebo, eu mostro ela em uma MessageBox.Show()

Comment: fiz uma resposta ve se funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Configure então assim: (*mediante comentário*)

```
WebClient webClientSummonerInfo0 = new WebClient();
webClientSummonerInfo0.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

[***WebClient.Encoding Propriedade***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Perfeito! Eu não sabia que a classe WebClient() tinha disso, saiu exatamente como esperado. Valeu!

Comment: Tem sim, Ok, @ÍcaroDantas !!!